# how to update frame

Tags: java, eclipse

to reload my JFrame I tried

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(startframe.this.getPanel());
```

and

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(startframe.this);
            startframe.this.invalidate();
            startframe.this.validate();
            startframe.this.repaint();
```

i also tried

```
startframe.this.revalidate();
```

but still non of them work

I also tried

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public synchronized void run()
                {
                    try{
                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public synchronized void run()
                        {
                            new listener();
                        }
                    });
                    }catch(Exception ee){
                        ee.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
                    t.start();
```

but that make some components missing

I also tried thread without SwingUtilites but the same problem too

I don`t want use

```
new startframe();
startframe.this.dispose();
```

because it doesn`t look good

how to solve then?????

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `frame.revalidate()`after you do your stuff in the frame . I hope I helped!

Comment: that wont help with anything ...listener class(extends ActionListener) create startframe(extends JFrame) in constructor